# extending local modules to global modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a scheme and $x \in X$. Consider the functor

$\text{Qcoh}(X) \to \mathcal{O}_{X,x} \text{-Mod} , M \mapsto M_x.$

Does it have a right-inverse? I.e. is there, for every $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module $N$ a (functorial) quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $M$ such that there is a natural isomorphism $M_x \cong N$?

If $X$ is quasi-separated, the answer is yes. First observe that, if $X$ is affine, the direct image with respect to $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) \to X$ works. Now if $X$ is quasi-separated, use the affine case to extend $N$ to a quasi-coherent module on an open affine neighborhood $U$ of $x$, and then take the direct image with respect to $U \to X$. This works since $U \to X$ is a quasi-compact, quasi-separated morphism.

In the general case, note that direct images don't work, but this does not disprove the existence of the functor I'm looking for. The question is motivated by [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37171/recover-a-morphism-from-its-pullback), which is still unsolved.

If $\mathfrak{m}_x \subseteq \text{rad}(\text{Ann}(N))$, then the direct image with respect to $\text{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\text{Ann}(N)) \to X$ (this is then an affine morphism!) works.

**EDIT**: A stronger, but more natural question is the following: Let $U \subseteq X$ an open subset. Does then $res : \text{Qcoh}(X) \to \text{Qcoh}(U)$ have a right inverse? As I said, this is clear if $U \to X$ is a quasi-compact morphism. In general, a transfinite recursion on the length of an affine cover shows that it is enough to consider the case that $X$ is affine, but $U \subseteq X$ arbitrary. Then everything is ok when $U$ is quasi-compact. In general, you can write $U$ as a directed union of quasi-compact subsets of $X$. Does this help somehow?

**EDIT 2**: There *is* a right adjoint $\text{Qcoh}(U) \to \text{Qcoh}(X)$ to the restriction functor due to [abstract reasons](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40587/quasi-coherent-envelope-of-a-module). If $X$ is affine, it maps $N$ to the module associated to $\Gamma(U,N)$, where the latter is considered as a $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$-module. However, this fails to be an extension of $N$, i.e. the counit $\widetilde{\Gamma(U,N)}|_U \to N$ is no isomorphism in general (I have an explicit counterexample). Thus, the desired right-inverse (if it exists) won't be a right adjoint.

**EDIT 3**: Here is a class of examples where extension works. Assume $X$ is affine and $U \subseteq X$ open can be written as $\coprod_{i \in I} U_i$ with $U_i$ affine. If $M \in \text{Qcoh}(U)$ and $M_i := \Gamma(U_i,M)$, then $\widetilde{\Gamma(U,M)} = \widetilde{\prod_{i \in I} M_i} \in \text{Qcoh}(X)$ is not an extension of $M$, but $\widetilde{\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i}$ works.

**EDIT 4**: Let $U,X,M$ as in edit 3. Then an application of Zorn's lemma shows that $M$ can be extended to a maximal open subset $U \subseteq V \subseteq X$. Then for every open affine $W \subseteq X$, either $V \cap W = W$ or $V \cap W$ is not quasi-compact. In particular, $V$ is ("very") dense. For example, $\mathbb{A}^{\infty} - \{0\} \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{\infty}$ is such a dense subset. But I don't know if here extension works. I've already looked at several examples, but have not found out anything ..

**EDIT 5**: If $dim(X)=0$, then extension works.

Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: Is the answer known if we forget about functoriality? In other words, is every $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$-module the stalk of some quasicoherent $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module?

Comment: @Laurent: Perhaps this simplifies the question, but also I don't know how to answer it.

Comment: If $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ is a PID and $N$ is finitely generated, then there is an extension $M$ (Reduce to the case $N=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ or $N=\mathcal{O}_{X,x} / \mathfrak{m}_x^n$ and use the last remark).

Comment: @Martin: The question in your first edit is exactly the question answered by Grothendieck-style monadic descent.  