# Open/closed embeddings and the de Rham space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules, crystals

Let $U\to X$ be an open immersion of schemes and denote by $D$ the (say reduced) complement. Then by applying the de Rham functor, we get morphisms
$$U_{dR}\to X_{dR}\leftarrow D_{dR}$$
of the associated de Rham spaces. Then in [this](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/GL/Crystalstext.pdf)  (in 2.5.2) Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum say that $U_{dR}\to X_{dR}$ is an open embedding.
It looks like they are proving this using the functorial description of open embeddings via $QCoh$, but instead for $IndCoh$. Its not clear to me that we also have a description of openness via $IndCoh$, do you know of a good reference for it? Once we have that, I think using $IndCoh(X_{dR})=\text{Crys}(X)$ and Kashiwara shows that the map is an open embedding.

My question is what do we know $D_{dR}\to X_{dR}$? Is it also a closed embedding? Naively you would think so, since we can see via the functor of points that $D_{dR}$ is the complement of $X_{dR}$, and the complement of a open substack ought to be a closed substack. Is this correct?

Comment: What is the functorial description of open embeddings via $QCoh$? Note also that $QCoh$ and $IndCoh$ coincide for de Rham prestacks locally almost of finite type; I.e. left and right $D$-modules coincide

Comment: I mean https://mathoverflow.net/q/1417

Comment: Typically properties of morphisms are defined through base change to affines. I think the point of that section is the fully faithfulness result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the following is a counter example to the claim in the last paragraph. Let $X$ be a smooth affine curve for simplicity, and let $pt \to X$ be a closed point. Consider the canonical map $X \to X_{dR}$. Then $D := X \times_{X_{dR}} pt$ is the formal completion of the point, and the map

$$D \longrightarrow X $$

is not a closed immersion.

Comment: Isn't it? I'm not sure what's the precise definition of a closed immersion in this case, but I certainly would like to imagine that this is a closed immersion. For example, take $X$ to be $\mathbb{A}^1$. In this case, your map is simply the inclusion of the nilpotent elements, which surely is a monomorphism. (And, for example, for algebraic groups we have that closed immersions and monomorphisms of sheaves are the same.)

Comment: @Gabriel Maybe it depends on your definition of closed embedding, but it’s not a closed embedding for the silly reason that $D$ is not a scheme. That said, it is indeed an “ind-closed” embedding in the sense that it’s induced by an inductive system of closed immersions to the curve